# open page in new tab in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using angularjs framework. I have ng-grid having a column containing link text. On that link click, I want to navigate to different page within the same application. I wanted to pass some parameters to another page, so I used ng-click and then method name. So, my code is like this:

```
<div class="ngCellText"><a data-ng-click="methodName(parameters)"> Go to Page2 </a>
```

Inside method:

```
document.location.href = '/Home/page2/
```

I used target=_blank but it did not work. Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) method

```
$window.open('/Home/page2/');
```

Comment: Except use angular's `$window` service so it's testable :)

Comment: Great.! It opens in new tab but the value which I want to pass on page2 is lost. I am using service to pass the parameters.

Comment: @Maddy That's an entirely different problem, you could serialize them in a query string or add them to localStorage, or something else. This isn't really a question regarding angular at this point.